# How to get a Protein Data Bank API Post to work

Tags: python, python-requests, protein-database

I am working through the example API post request at https://alignment.rcsb.org/#submit-alignment-job.  I submit the job exactly as shown below with the exact endpoint and query of their example but I get a 404 response.  I have tried restructuring the query and have tried other examples on their page but it continually gives me the 404 response.  How can I get this to work?

```
def submittwostructstoPDB():
    import requests

    url="https://alignment.rcsb.org/api/v1/structures/submit/"
    jsontext={"context":{"mode":"pairwise","method":{"name":"fatcat-rigid"},"structures":[{"entry_id":"8HSK","selection":{"asym_id":"A"}},{"entry_id":"8HSF","selection":{"asym_id": "A"}}]}}
        
    
    response = requests.post(url, json = jsontext)
        
    return response

submittwostructstoPDB()
```